# On solutions of $\varphi(n)=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}\varphi(dn)$, where $\varphi(m)$ denotes the Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function, perfect-numbers, dirichlet-convolution

I wondered if one can to get easily an answer for the following question (I have thought about the other direction $\Leftarrow$). I don't know if it is in the literature, please refer it in comments in such case.

We denote the Euler's totient function as $\varphi(m)$, the Wikipedia encyclopedia has the article [*Euler's totient function.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

**Conjecture.** *Let* $n\geq 1$ *be an integer satisfying the identity*
$$\varphi(n)=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}\varphi(dn),\tag{1}$$
*then* $n$ *is an even perfect number.*

Due that it isn't unknown if there exists odd perfect numbers I don't know if my question (the following question) is difficult, using elementary computations from $(1)$. It is known that the Euler's totient function is multiplicative and I know also properties of multiplicative functions and Möbius inversion.

> **Question.** Is it true previous conjecture? **Many thanks.**

My only idea is that maybe can be useful to use the representation of the Euler's totient function as a Dirichlet convolution. If my conjecture is known from the literature feel free to answer as a reference request, and I try to search an read the statement from the literature.

With a Pari/GP script (or similar than these that I can to evaluate)

`for(n=1,100000,if(2*n*eulerphi(n)==sumdiv(n,d,eulerphi(d*n)),print(n)))`

you can to see that there aren't small counterexamples, just copy and paste previous code in the web *Sage Cell Server* and choose as language *GP* to evaluate it.

Comment: As a reference for this post I add also Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to analytic number theory*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics, New York-Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag (1976).

Comment: Also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344754/around-a-characterization-for-even-perfect-numbers-similar-than-euclides-euler) discusses a similar question.

Comment: Yes, many thanks I know it @DietrichBurde . A great feedback.